# Customised batch processing of PSD files (Adobe Photoshop / Adobe InDesign)

Tags: excel, actionscript, photoshop, psd, adobe-indesign

I have some 200 Photoshop templates with me and I want to be able to add certain images and text to each template separately.The path to the image as well as the text is given in an excel file which again has 200 rows.So basically template1 should contain image and text from row1, template2 from row2 and so on. Could any one please direct me in the right direction?

Thanking you,
niting

Comment: I don't think you can go directly from excel to photoshop, so first export the excel data as XML or CSV or so. Then use photoshop scripting, which is javascript-based, to do your batch processing, after loading the XML/CSV from excel (see [Photoshop scripting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html))

Comment: Oh! Thanks alot for that answer. Will look it up. I guess you should put that in the answers section :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Based on my comment above:*

I don't think you can go directly from excel to photoshop, so first export the excel data as XML or CSV or so. Then use photoshop scripting, which is javascript-based, to do your batch processing, after loading the XML/CSV from excel (see [Photoshop scripting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html))

Good luck! :)